# $\bigcup_{p>r}L_p(\lambda)$ is of category 1 in $L_r(\lambda)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(\Omega, S,\lambda)$ be a measure space where $\Omega=(0,1),\; S=\Bbb B_{(0,1)},\;\lambda\text{ is Lebesgue measure over } S$. I want to prove the following:

> $$\bigcup_{p>r} L_p(\lambda)\text{  is category 1  in }\ L_r(\lambda)
> $$

Clearly $\bigcup_{p>r}L_p(\lambda)\subset L_r(\lambda)$. I have already proved that $\forall p>r\ge 1\;\; L_p(\lambda)$ is of category 1 in $L_r(\lambda)$ but got stucked trying to show that it follows that $\bigcup_{p>r}L_p(\lambda)$ is of category 1 in $L_r(\lambda)$, since I can't assure how an arbitrary union of category 1 sets in $L_r(\lambda)$ is still a category 1 set in $L_r(\lambda)$. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\bigcup_{p>r} L_p(\lambda)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty L_{r+\frac{1}{n}}(\lambda)
$$

Comment: Ok, since
$$
\forall n\in\Bbb N\;\;L_{r+\frac{1}{n}}(\lambda) \text{  is of category 1 in  }\; L_r(\lambda)
$$
we get then that 
$$
\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N} L_{r+\frac{1}{n}} \text{  is of category 1 in  }\; L_r(\lambda)
$$
and thus $$\bigcup_{p>r}L_p(\lambda)\text{  is of category 1 in}\;L_r(\lambda)$$

Comment: Correct$\phantom{}$

Comment: Now I have doubt. How could it be posible that a countable union of category 1 sets is still of category 1? I've been trying but have not got anything. If $\forall n\in\Bbb N\;E_n$ is of category 1 in $X$ then for every $n\in\Bbb N\;\;E_n=\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N}F_{kn}$, where $F_{kn}$ is nowhere dense for every $k\in\Bbb N$. So, I need to show that 
$$\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}E_n=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N}F_{kn}$$
is a countable union of nowhere dense sets, but can't figure out how from here. I only get that
$$\bigcup_{k\in\Bbb N}\bar F_{kn}\subset \bar E_n\;\;\forall n\in\Bbb N$$

Comment: why bother about closures?

Comment: because I need to show that $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}E_n$ is a countable union of nowhere dense sets to prove that is of category 1 and a nowhere dense set is such that the interior of its closure is empty

Comment: Each $F_{kn}$ is nowhere dense, and the family $\{F_{kn}:k,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is countable. Nothing left to prove.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks!